# User data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a very large google sheet that multiple team members (about 65) log into each day.  The challenge is that they all work remotely.  I am trying to figure out a way to get a report each day of how many changes each person made to the google sheet so I can see who was working and who was not.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can only see modifications, which isn't a very good way of telling if work was accomplished.

Comment: Can I export the username of who did the modification?   That is what I am trying to find a way to complete.